# Membership Structure Help

Tags: civimember

I have some questions about structuring our memberships, we have two branch locations, is there a way in the membership reporting to show the reports on each location? or do I have to create types such as "Family Location 1" & "Family Location 2"

In addition to this we also have tier memberships based on normal incomes and low income in each location.

Here is a screen shot of what we currently have, we are in development so this is not live yet.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated

Zeak

Comment: You say "Membership Reporting" but I think this is the Membership dashboard, not a report.  If this is a report, which report template are you using as a base?  Is it acceptable to have two reports/dashlets - one for each location?

Answer (score 1):

it seems quite a simple solution to simply have an extra pair of Membership Types, eg Individual Locality A, and Individual Locality B. That would ensure that the 'location' data was always immediately available to you when look at membership data. anything else is likely to require some customisations in order to show that information in the membership context.